# cancel the onchange event via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'have a list option list contains onchange="setLocation(this.value)"

```
<div class="sort-by">
    <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=position">Position</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=name">Name</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=price">Price</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=created_at" selected="selected">Date</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=end_date">End date</option>
        <option value="Range">Range</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I have some jQuery afterwards will append some value

```
selectValues = { "Range": "Range" };
jQuery.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {   
    jQuery('.sort-by select').append(jQuery("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(value));
});
```

When a user select a specific I want to cancel the `setLocation` and do another operation

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.sort-by select').change(function(){
        var selectedVal = jQuery(".sort-by select option:selected").val();

        if (selectedVal == "Range") {
            return false;    
        }
    });
});
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what is .sort-by select, is it the same select input as in the question

Comment: one way to do it is to remove the onchange attribute and do a if in the jquery change function

Comment: if you are any attaching a change event through jquery then why are you attaching a onchange attribute on your element, call that method inside your jquery change event based on your condition

Answer (score 0):

Use `removeAttr` and remove the onClick event.

```js
$('select').removeAttr('onchange');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
    <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=position">Position</option>
    <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=name">Name</option>
    <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=price">Price</option>
    <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=created_at" selected="selected">Date</option>
    <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=end_date">End date</option>
    <option value="Range">Range</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the onchange attribute

```
<div class="sort-by">
    <select>
        <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=position">Position</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=name">Name</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=price">Price</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=created_at" selected="selected">Date</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/test.html?dir=asc&amp;order=end_date">End date</option>
        <option value="Range">Range</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Change the if statement

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.sort-by select').change(function(){
        var selectedVal = jQuery(".sort-by select option:selected").val();

        if (selectedVal != "Range") {
            setLocation(selectedVal);  
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can empty the attribute and unbind the event

**Jquery pre 1.7**

```
$('select').attr('onchange','').unbind('onchange');
```

**Jquery post 1.7**

```
$('select').prop('onchange','').unbind('onchange');
```

Or you can do **removeAttr** also depends on you way of execution

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.sort-by select').change(function(){
    var selectedVal = jQuery(".sort-by select option:selected").val();

    if (selectedVal == "Range") {
        return false;    
    }
    $(this).attr('onchange','').unbind('onchange'); // or .prop()
   });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't really answer the OP question.